# In Elasticsearch, how can I retrieve products grouped by the store that sells them?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a bunch of stores, each of which sells several products, and those products have descriptions. I would like to build a search experience where the user can search for products by words in the description, and have a search result page where matching products are shown, grouped by the store that sells them. My question is:

How can I design an efficient Elasticsearch schema and query scheme that will let me query for products with the results grouped by store, with the guarantee that every store in the search results contains a complete list of items that match the query?

---

For instance, suppose I had the following data:

- Store 1

  - Product 1a, description: "Peanut butter and jelly sandwich"
  - Product 1b, description: "Taco"
  - Product 1c, description: "Sandwich holder"
- Store 2

  - Product 2a, description: "Burrito bowl"
- Store 3

  - Product 3a, description: "Sandwich maker"
  - Product 3b, description: "Sandwich bread"
  - Product 3c, description: "Salad tongs"

In my overall application, I want a query for "sandwich" to return something like:

- Store 1

  - product 1a
  - product 1c
- Store 3

  - product 3a
  - product 3b

Whenever I show a store, I always want to show *all* hits for that store. In the domain I'm working in, there are lots of stores but each store only has a small number of products (max of around 10-20, with most stores only having 2 or 3).

I can see two ways to implement this, and both seem bad to me.

#### Approach #1

Index each product is a separate document. Then at query time, I could fetch every matching document and post-process them in Java to group them by store, and finally return that result. The problems I see with this approach are:

- I can't use any kind of ranking, since I'm going to re-sort the results.
- I also can't do any limiting; I have to fetch every single document, no matter how many there may be, since otherwise I can't guarantee that I have every product for a particular store. This will result in lots of wasted work.

#### Approach #2

Index each store as a separate document, with a nested field holding each product. At query time, I could retrieve stores where the product description nested field has a match on the search term. Then, once I have the stores I want to show, I'd have to run a separate query to fetch the matching products from those stores. The problems with this approach are:

- I'm asking elasticsearch to do more work than necessary; internally, it had find everything I needed in the first query, but I'm asking a second query anyway
- Issuing two related queries complicates the code and requires me to keep two queries in sync (e.g. I need to make sure that the documents matched in query 1 as subfields are the same documents that query 2 matches)

---

Can anyone more experienced with Elasticsearch than I am see a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Approach#2 I see 2 options:

1. [Nested inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits).
2. You could use [top_hits with reverse_nested aggregator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_top_hits_support_in_a_nested_or_reverse_nested_aggregator). You'll search for the products in query and you'll group the docs by store in the aggregator. The top_hits aggregation returns regular search hits meaning you'll get the children(products) along with the parent(store).

Comment: this approach will be expensive if say we have thousands of products in every shop, and running the query at very high rps. Is there any other alternative?